# setup android on eclipse but don't know SDK directory

Tags: android, eclipse

According to the beginner guide, to setup the ADT Plugin, one of the procedures is

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

> For the SDK Location in the main
>   panel, click Browse... and locate your
>   downloaded SDK directory.

I went to Program Files, found Android directory, but none of those works.
Upon research, I found out that Android developers have warned me to take note of the SDK directory, which I didn't.

Now my question is, how do I get that directory path? I don't want to reinstall the SDK, and then install the updates (lots of mess...)

Thanks for the help!

---

**Edited**

That exe that you guys wanted me to look for is indeed inside platform-tools.

I installed Android SDK, and it gives me Android SDK Manager. So I am guessing I had the right thing installed on my PC.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can search your hard drive for one of the programs that's installed with the SDK. For instance, if you search for `aapt.exe` or `adb.exe`, they will be in the `platform-tools` directory *underneath* the installation directory (which is what you're after).

Answer (score 69):

The path to the SDK is:

> C:\Users\**USERNAME**\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

This can be used in Eclipse after you replace USERNAME with your Windows user name.

Comment: This should belong to a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @b.enoit.be Why it should be a comment? This is a correct answer where the sdk folder is located and it helped me a lot.

Comment: +1 This is where Android Studio puts the SDK.  For those that don't know, AppData is hidden by default.  On Win8, click 'View' on the menu and check 'Hidden items'.

Comment: @steebchen because you are formatting and wording it as a question. Be assertive in your answers, so that reviewer (that do not always have technical knowledge on the post they review) are not mistakenly taking them as question, as I did. So for your answer and for further ones, you may want to avoid thinks like "Thanks" in...

Comment: As of Android SDK 24.0.2, it seems to install (using Chocolatey) @ C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Comment: Huh, why would they put it in the AppData folder?

Answer (score 12):

Search (Ctrl+F) your harddrive(s) for:  **SDK Manager.exe**  or  **adb.exe**

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. I actually tried, it's within platform-tools. Please look at the updated post. The screenshot shows that this path didn't allow me to proceed the setup.

Answer (score 5):

The Android SDK directory is just the folder you get after uncompressing one of these files:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

There's no such "SDK installation"... may be, what you installed was the ADT plugin (which does not include the SDK). You have to download one of the ZIP files you find in the link above, uncompress it and boila! you have the SDK Folder.

Comment: I installed the Android SDK (On the Start program menu the directory is called "Android SDK Tools") . I followed this and checked all and installed in eclipse. http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Answer (score 5):

Late to the conversion...

For me, I found this at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

This is the default location for Windows 64-bit.

Also, try to recall some of your default locations when not presented with some suggestions.

Comment: Searching for `adb.exe` yielded no results for me, so I went straight to `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk` and there it was! :)

Comment: It also helps running the android studio installer and see the location where its going to install the new sdk, there is your old one too

Comment: If you install for "all users," this is where it goes.  If you install for "just you," then it goes to the username\appdata\local directory mentioned by Tech Solutions

Answer (score 2):

a simple windows search for `android-sdk` should help you find it, assuming you named it that.  You also might just wanna try `sdk`

Comment: updated the post. i found that path but didn't work out. thanks for the help thus far

Answer (score 1):

May be i am too much late here and question is already answered, but this may help those who still cannot find sdk location. Open eclipse, click window tab it will show a drop down menu, click preferences, in preferences window click Android, here u go Sdk location is right in front of u copy the address :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it in this location:

**C:\Users\amitsinha02\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools**

Answer (score 0):

> ADT Plugin (UNSUPPORTED)

The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported, as per this announcement in June 2015.

The Eclipse ADT plugin has many known bugs and potential security bugs that will not be fixed.

You should immediately switch to use Android Studio, the official IDE for Android.

For help transitioning your projects, read Migrate to Android Studio.