# Android SDK location

Tags: android, sdk, xamarin-studio

I have Xamarin Studio, and I need to specify the Android SDK Location. I have previously had Xamarin Studio working on my pc, and for some reason, I need to enter this again.

I have entered the following location:

`C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

Xamarin Studio does not accept this location and displays the following message:

```
No SDK found at the specified location
```

This location has platform-tools and other SDK folders.

Why is this not working, and what should I do?

Comment: some helps for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672562/setup-android-on-eclipse-but-dont-know-sdk-directory

Comment: where you installed your SDk give that path

Comment: The path to the SDK you're specifying is indeed the correct path.

Is it possible the SDK-install got damaged in some way? Have you tried reinstalling the SDK? Same question for Xamarin?

Comment: It is usually `C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Do you have a screen of the content of your folder? This is my setup:

[image: Xamarin]

[image: Folder]

I hope these screenshots can help you out.

Comment: I usually don't consider my username as a secret.

Comment: Even if it's something very offensive? ( actually i have no idea why i scribbled it out, but i'm glad people appreciate my fine computer art )

Comment: The menu is File > Settings

Answer (score 239):

**Update v3.3**

[image]

**Update:**

Android Studio 3.1 update, some of the icon images have changed. Click this icon in Android Studio.

[image]

**Original:**

Click this icon in Android Studio for the Android SDK manager

[image]

And your Android SDK Location will be here
[image]

Comment: he is trying to locate sdk for xamarin.

Comment: its android studio youre using

Comment: You can just copy-paste this if you have installed Android Studio with Android SDK %localappdata%\Android\sdk

Comment: `Tools->Android->SDK Manager` if you cannot find the icon.

Answer (score 67):

The Android SDK path is usually `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Comment: This varies.  My android studio points to the directory that you have published. However if I just open SDK manager. It points to  `\android-sdk`

Answer (score 15):

Try to open the Android Sdk manager and the path would be displayed on the status bar.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

The default location for Android sdk(s) on a Mac is:

`/Users/*username*/Library/Android/sdk`

Answer (score 10):

If you only installed **Xamarin** with Visual Studio setup, the android SDK location is :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

You can find it in Android SDK Manager as said [Raj Asapu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086736/155622)

In visual Studio :
[image: Android SDK Manger from Visual Studio]

Note : you should not use Program Files path to install **Android Studio** due to the space in path !
[image: Android studio setup after Xamarin]

Answer (score 7):

When you first time install Android Studio Setup, you can also see the SDK folder.
For me it is:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**On 28 April 2019 official procedure is the following:**

1. Download and install Android Studio from - [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads)
2. Start Android Studio. On first launch, the Android Studio will download latest Android SDK into officially accepted folder
3. When Android studio finish downloading components you can copy/paste path from the "Downloading Components" view logs so you don't need to type your [Username]. For Windows: "**C:\Users\ [Username] \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**"

Comment: I skipped step 2 myself as I though by installing Android studio you will get SDK as well, but that is not the case. You must start studio to finish installation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to find this folder via the Windows explorer? Can it been seen?
Maybe the folder is hidden (by default install - it is hidden by the Windows operating system in the users folder). Just check that you can view hidden folders in Windows explorer (by the settings in the windows control panel > appearance and personalization > folder options > show hidden files and folders.

This happened to me as the Windows OS could not find the SDK folder which was required for the Android Studio SDK path, and was resolved by showing hidden files and folders, which enabled me to complete the default SDK install path location.

Answer (score 3):

press [WIN+R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew4vi.png) and from the run dialog [run dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ezNk.png)
Execute the following: `%appdata%\..\Local\Android\`

You should now be presented with Folder Explorer displaying the parent directory of the SDK.

Comment: You can access the local folder imminently instead of folder travelsal
`%localappdata%Android`

Answer (score 3):

If you can run the "sdkmanager" from the command line, then running `sdkmanager --verbose --list` will reveal the paths it checks.

For example, I have installed the SDK in `c:\spool\Android` and for me running the `sdkmanager --verbose --list` looks like:

[image]

```
>sdkmanager --list --verbose
Info: Parsing c:\spool\Android\build-tools\27.0.3\package.xml
Info: Parsing c:\spool\Android\emulator\package.xml
Info: Parsing c:\spool\Android\extras\android\m2repository\package.xml
Info: Parsing c:\spool\Android\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
Info: Parsing c:\spool\Android\patcher\v4\package.xml
Info: Parsing c:\spool\Android\platform-tools\package.xml
Info: Parsing c:\spool\Android\platforms\android-27\package.xml
Info: Parsing c:\spool\Android\tools\package.xml
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...
--------------------------------------
build-tools;27.0.3
    Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
    Version:            27.0.3
    Installed Location: c:\spool\Android\build-tools\27.0.3
```

P.S. On another PC I let the Android Studio install the Android SDK for me, and the SDK ended up in `C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't seem to *require* a programmatic solution, but my Google search brought me here anyway. Here's my C# attempt at detecting where the SDK is installed, based on the most common installation paths.

```
static string FindAndroidSDKPath()
{
    string uniqueFile = Path.Combine("platform-tools", "adb.exe"); // look for adb in Android folders
    string[] searchDirs =
    {
        // User/AppData/Local
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        // Program Files
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
        // Program Files (x86) (it's okay if we're on 32-bit, we check if this folder exists first)
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + " (x86)",
        // User/AppData/Roaming
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    };
    foreach (string searchDir in searchDirs)
    {
        string androidDir = Path.Combine(searchDir, "Android");
        if (Directory.Exists(androidDir))
        {
            string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(androidDir, "*sdk*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            foreach (string subDir in subDirs)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(subDir, uniqueFile);
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    // found unique file at DIR/Android
                    return subDir;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // no luck finding SDK! :(
    return null;
}
```

I need this because I'm writing an extension to a C# program to work with Android Studio/Gradle. Hopefully someone else will find this approach useful.

Comment: Another useful approach might be to search the environment PATH, as seen here: http://csharptest.net/526/how-to-search-the-environments-path-for-an-exe-or-dll/index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have downloaded sdk manager zip (from  https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads), then you have Android SDK Location as root of the extracted folder.

So silly, But it took time for me as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I found it here C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk .

Comment: What value is your answer adding? There is almost exactly the same answer already.

Comment: I like this answer because it is articulate. : )

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS Catalina with zsh:

`echo '\nexport PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/Library/Android/sdk"' >> $HOME/.zshrc`

restart the terminal and voila :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new empty directory that path is “/Users/*username*/Library/Android/sdk”.
Then reopen it.

Comment: Please explain the difference of your recommended solution to the existing older and upvoted answer by Pankaj.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have the correct '/', sometimes it doesn't work with ''. It is in that way windows copies it as part of locals paths

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing the region language to the United State was a main factor in the solution.

the steps:
1- [Change the region language to the United State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMO2U.png)

2- Download the android SDK manually and put it in the following path: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

3- install the SDK from Android Studio

Note: AppData is hidden by default

you can find the steps in details and links to download the SDK [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJJkQ4oFdjg)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can find SDK path here:
[image]