# "Gradle sync failed: No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher"

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic2

I'm trying to open an Ionic2 Project in Android Studio, but it gives me the following error into the Event Log: 
"**Gradle sync failed: No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.** Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"
[**SCREENSHOT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGm8C.png)

I have seen a similiar problem stated before (also maybe one of the latest release of Ionic2 or Cordova broke something -> https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10604).

Changing the version of "buildToolsVersion" or "compileSdkVersion" from gradle.build file or from Project Structure didn't help.

Under "C:\Users\Gaby\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.3", I installed the 24.0.3 build tool version.

The *path* variable from environment variables indicates also the path correctly

At one moment, I had all build-tools installed with "android update sdk -u -a" but again, the same error occured.

Does anybody know a suitable workaround to this issuse ?

Many thanks

Comment: can you see any buildTools installed if you open SDK-Manager?

Comment: @Yazan, yes. according to SDK Manager I have the following installed: 19.1.0, 20.0.0, 24.02 (none of them is mentioned to be obsolete)

Comment: The cordova does not find environment path correctly, but the path set correctly.

Comment: You must run your command as root user. Sudo is not enough. So run "sudo -s" to change to root. And re-run your command again

Comment: https://www.programmersought.com/article/89467857203/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to write the correct "Environment Variables".
See: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

Windows:

```
setx ANDROID_SDK_ROOT "C:\android-sdk-windows"
setx PATH "%PATH%;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools"
```

Mac OS X

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

Linux

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

> Update: **ANDROID_HOME** is deprecated, **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** is now the correct variable

Comment: Please where can i download the full version of Android SDK?

Answer (score 18):

First of all  make sure **build tools are installed**.

After that open terminal on **MacOS** and **change .bash_profile** file:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

you should add following lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms
```

ctrl+O and ctrl+X

**reload android studio**

Comment: For me the `:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` is what was missing from my PATH and solved the problem

Comment: Thank you, on Fedora the first line should be 
`export ANDROID_HOME=/home/<user>/Android/Sdk`

Comment: @AvramVirgil Feel free to edit my answer to add your note about Fedora.

Answer (score 12):

If you set ANDROID_STUDIO enviroment variable properly, than it means that, you have not installed build tools.

Rename the tools folder in %ANDROID_HOME% to tools_old, then
With command line interface use:

```
sdkmanager tools --verbose
```

Old tools folder (tools_old) can be deleted, use the updated sdkmanager:

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.1" --verbose
```

The version number can be different. Use:

```
sdkmanager --list --verbose > packages.txt
```

Check the packages.txt file for available versions.

Comment: I tried so many ways by adding path to bash_profile. None of them worked. This works!

Comment: Many thanks! This worked for me `sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.3" --verbose`

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was produced by a wrong ANDROID_HOME path.

I've modified my ANDROID_HOME path is pointing to C:\android-sdk. This folder contains the below files

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTc0o.jpg]

I hope this helps

Comment: helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1.Open Android studio
2.Go to SDK Manager
3.Then Appearance and Behaviour ->System Setting -> Android SDK
4.SDK Tools
5.Select Android SDK Build Tools
6.install 19.1.0

Build Tools
[image: Build Tools]

Comment: Yes! This is the answer!!

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable `doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools()` method in `cordova.gradle` and manually specify the `buildToolsVersion` in cordova `build.gradle` file as below

```
android{
   buildToolsVersion "specify the build tools version here"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X

```
cd ~
nano ~/.bash_profile

export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

echo $ANDROID_HOME // Verify the path

source ~/.bash_profile
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Environment Variables" ,`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

 [Android SDK location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location)

Answer (score 0):

- Add `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to your Environment Varibales  =>  System Variables.
- `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` should contain the Android SDK path , my path was
  `C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error message because *both* `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` variables were defined

Something like this :

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/path/to/Android"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$ANDROID_HOME/sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools
```

In that case, it looks like `ANDROID_HOME` was taking precedence over `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

Once I removed `ANDROID_HOME` variable it solved my problem magically :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes just recheck `local.properties` and run build command from terminal

Comment: Grammer error. Remove "of a" word from sentance

Answer (score 0):

In my case i open my cordova.gradle in android Studio, i tried to build it, despite i have installed the build-tools 33.0.2 i still says No installed build tools found. I tried to log the getAndroidSdkDir() and i found the error. In my env variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT "C:/users/johndoe/appData/android/Sdk" the variable i log is "C:/users/johndoe/appData/android" without the Sdk folder. In the doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools() function i add the "Sdk" before the "build-tools" and it works.... Hope this helps i spend a couple days on it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for some reason when installing SDK 34 it decided to change the folder name from ..Android\sdk to ..Android\Sdk (with an uppercase S) so I changed that in the environment variables and it worked.