# Error:No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

I am working on android project and every thing works fine, but when I started a new cordova project then it throw error `Error:No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.`

I search on google and in most of answer says `change in ANDROID_PATH`.

My current `ANDROID_HOME` path is `C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;`

but still I can't figure out the problem.

I found exactly similar question ["Gradle sync failed: No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029394/gradle-sync-failed-no-installed-build-tools-found-install-the-android-build-t) but still I am not able to solve it.

Here some of my cordova.gradle code

```
ext {
  // These helpers are shared, but are not guaranteed to be stable / unchanged.
  privateHelpers = {}
  privateHelpers.getProjectTarget = { doGetProjectTarget() }
  privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools = { doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools('19.1.0') }
  privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest = { name -> doExtractIntFromManifest(name) }
  privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest = { name -> doExtractStringFromManifest(name) }
  privateHelpers.promptForPassword = { msg -> doPromptForPassword(msg) }
  privateHelpers.ensureValueExists = { filePath, props, key -> doEnsureValueExists(filePath, props, key) }

  // These helpers can be used by plugins / projects and will not change.
  cdvHelpers = {}
  // Returns a XmlParser for the config.xml. Added in 4.1.0.
  cdvHelpers.getConfigXml = { doGetConfigXml() }
  // Returns the value for the desired <preference>. Added in 4.1.0.
  cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference = { name, defaultValue ->  doGetConfigPreference(name, defaultValue) }
 }
```

If any one need more info about env_valiable let me know, I will update it.

Edit: When I did `android update sdk -u -a -t <package no.>` then it says `Filter <package no> is not supported`

Comment: What's your version of Build Tools?

Comment: @Edric In my other project its `buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'`

Comment: @Edric are you here ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the folder name is `sdk`, not `Sdk`.

Comment: @Edric in my system folder name is `Sdk`

Comment: Here's how to change where the SDK directory is found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541883/6782707

Comment: Did you get answer ? , have same issue here.

Comment: Same issue, answer please?