# problem : Gradle sync failed: No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher. (7 s 246 ms)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, sdk

**hello every one**
**first of all please excuse my bad english**
i had a  project which i wanted to build through android studio
i got a failure message :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

    Script 'A:\New folder\into dragosan caves trial 2\build\into dragosan caves trial 2\into dragosan caves trial 2\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 66

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.
```

**i already have sdk and build tools instals**
**and i have fixed my enviroment variables probably also i guess**

**i used flutter doctor comand at cmd and got the following results :**

```
    C:\Users\Walaa>flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1415], locale ar-EG)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

```
**then i used sdkmanager --list command in cmd and got the following results :**
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...
  Path                 | Version | Description                    | Location
  -------              | ------- | -------                        | -------
  build-tools;31.0.0   | 31.0.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 31     | build-tools\31.0.0\
  build-tools;32.0.0   | 32.0.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 32     | build-tools\32.0.0\
  cmdline-tools;5.0    | 5.0     | Android SDK Command-line Tools | cmdline-tools\5.0\
  emulator             | 31.1.4  | Android Emulator               | emulator\
  patcher;v4           | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher\v4\
  platform-tools       | 31.0.3  | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools\
  platforms;android-30 | 3       | Android SDK Platform 30        | platforms\android-30\
  sources;android-30   | 1       | Sources for Android 30         | sources\android-30\
```

any help please ?

Comment: Please refer the following link. this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the

Comment: Hi Walaa ..Hope this answers solves the issue - > https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112267/6826629