# Android Profiler stuck in loading

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler

I am trying to opening Profiler but it's not working as it stucks in loading, I have Android Studio 3.3.

**Profiler stuck in loading**

[image: Profiler stuck in loading]

I am using this real device..

[image: My Android Device]

Answer (score 12):

If your platform-tools's version is 29.0.3 on Android Studio 3.5, please rollback version to 29.0.2.

I found it in google issue tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140822450

> I can confirm that downgrading to version 29.0.2 fixed the issue of not founding devices in the Android Profiler. You can download that version from here: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r29.0.2-darwin.zip. Unzip it in your Android SDK folder.

Comment: May be you are right. but when i tried your solution, android studio stopped detecting the device. Fortunately I had back up of platoform tools version 29.0.3.Your solution did not work in my case.

Comment: It works like a charm. Here is a good answer how to find a path to your sdk directory - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541883/9169701

Comment: Problem fixed in version 29.0.4

Comment: I had this issue even in 29.0.5. I fixed it by uninstalling and installing the platfom-tools. (SDK Tools -> uncheck Android SDK Platform-Tools -> apply -> check Android SDK Platform-Tools -> apply)

Answer (score 3):

Click on the '+' ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67psl.jpg)) signal!
This worked for me on Android Studio 3.5.1
with platform-tools's version 29.0.4

For me it was also showing the loading gif but just click on the '+' button and select your android!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for Android Studio 3.5.3, but I used a device on android 8.0, which is supposed to work fine with profiler, unlike 4.4. What I had to do was to update the platform tools from 29.0.2 to 29.0.5 and it finally started to work. You can find it in Tools - SDK Manager - Android SDK

[image]

Comment: I updated to latest then works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

that's because the profiler doesn't work with API 25 or lower levels.
when you are trying to start profiler you should see this message from Android Studio

[image: startup proofiling]

or you can check the Event log, and you'll see this message

> Startup CPU Profiling: Starting a method trace recording on startup is only supported on devices with API levels 26 and higher.

[image: Event log Messages]

---

so all you need is to change the phone which you are working on but be Ensure that have API Level 26 or higher.

when you change the API to higher one Ensure to do these Steps:-

1. disable instant Run from File > Settings > unmark enable instant run...
2. Enable advanced profiling from app > Edit Configuration > profiling > then mark on "like the image blew" ...

   - Enable Advanced Profiling.
   - Start Recording CPU Activity on startup.

[image: mark these]

> NOTE: YOU WILL FIND " APP " ON THE TOOLBAR.
>   [image]

finally, plug in your new device which has a higher API and start working on your app.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to use the Profiler with lower api devices,,?

Comment: @MuhammadAseel I think there's no alternative way to profile on your real device, but I think it'll work on a virtual device having API 26

Comment: I have tried reboot the machine, restart the phone, android reinstall IDE but the issue is still not resolved. My Android Studio's version is 3.5

Comment: Have same problem, nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact problem. Because I tried to use Profiler in lower API level of Android. In my case it was API level 19 (KitKat).

**Pre-Lollipop devices aren't supported by Profiler**

**Use the later (>21) or latest version of Android Devices for Profiling App**

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme, i fixed it by changing the targetSdkVersion to the version of my phone.
I had targetSdkVersion to 29 and the profiler wasn't loading.
Then i changed it to 28 that is my phone sdkversion then it worked fine.