# android-studio android-studio-dir location

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to get flutter/android studios to work on linux and i am having an issue getting flutter to recognize my android-studio location.

I am able to run android-stuio, but when i try to tell flutter my install location via the android-studio-dir param i get something that doesn't work.

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.27.0-2.0.pre.78, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ android-studio-dir = ~/Downloads/android-studio/bin/
    ✗ Android Studio not found at ~/Downloads/android-studio/bin/
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

At location ~/Downloads/android-studio/bin/ i have the bin directory of my android studio install. This obviously doesn't work.

I have tried to look up what directory android-studio-dir needs to point at and it seems that i wants to point at a directory like /path/to/android/studio.

but in my install directory i dont have a studio directory to point at?

So my question is what should android-studio-dir point at?

I am able to run android studio by ./~/Downloads/android-studio/bin/studio.sh

So i am fairly confident i have android studio "installed" correctly.

Comment: Use the complete path as `/home/user/Downloads/android-studio/` and remove the `bin` folder from path

Comment: the commands are `flutter config --android-sdk="/home/user/Android/Sdk"` and 
 `flutter config --android-studio-dir="/usr/local/android-studio"`

Comment: thanks that fixed it..

Comment: I'll post it as answer then.

Answer (score 19):

For windows the commands are same like those from @Doc, the slashes should be backslash though, here they are fixed:

```
flutter config --android-sdk="C:\TestFolder\AndroidSDK"
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```

Comment: i just installed flutter and android studio, where do i find Android SDK directory?

Comment: @tio_hecro https://stackoverflow.com/a/38193694/16345931

Answer (score 6):

the commands are

`flutter config --android-sdk="/home/user/Android/Sdk"`

`flutter config --android-studio-dir="/usr/local/android-studio"`

Don't use the `bin` folder, just mark the root folder for both the sdk and the IDE. Also, use complete path.

Answer (score 2):

A. To resolve your unrecognized sdk. issue, use following steps

1. Find your dir. location. You will find at same place

> C:\users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\SDK

Mine was at

> C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

2. Go to PowerShell and type

> flutter config --android-sdk
> "C:\users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\SDK"

Change your Username above

[PowerShell screenshot showing how I resolved unable to locate SDK issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJMc3.jpg)

B. To resolve dir issue, type

> flutter config --android-studio-dir "type directory name"

In my case, it was

> flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio"

C. I have license issue so I am sharing here if in case you encounter it after fixing SDK and dir issue.

C.1 Open you Android Studio

C.2 On main screen, Click Advanced > SDK Manager

[SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt9nU.png)

C.3 Select SDK Tools

Check Android SDK Command-line tools and click ‘apply’.
[Check Android SDK Command-line tools and click ‘apply’](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuwUd.png)

C.4 Click Apply.

C.5 Your license issue will be resolved. You can test it by again going to PowerShell and type

> flutter doctor
> You will pass all tests like I did in photo[flutter passed all tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Z01.jpg)

If you want to check your configurations for SDK, dir etc, just type flutter config and it will show you all configurations.

Answer (score 2):

For **macOS** User

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

Comment: You must add "quotes" If a value has a space in it, enclose it in quotes on the command line to make a single argument, 
flutter config --android-studio-dir /Applications/Android\ Studio.app