# How to resolve " This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered." ? - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

[image]

I am getting this error "This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.".

My app still working but this error is annoying.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70220347/warning-unexpected-element-uri-localbase-extension-after-android-targe

Answer (score 0):

Just update the emulator to a newer version (from 9th to 12th) https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#ki-android-11-db-inspector

Tools-> SDK manager -> Android SDK -> (select the version you want here) -> ok -> ok -> wait for the installation to finish, and voila, you're done

also try to put a higher version of the bulid.gradle file like: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'

Comment: For 2 weeks i tried to fix it but i could not, i will try your way when i am up to, thanks for your answer .