# Setting up the Android Studio directory on Flutter Doctor

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

I'm setting up an application development environment with Flutter.
I'm having trouble installing Android Studio: I can't set the directory where Android Studio is installed. I've got an error, as shown in the picture. How do I find the correct directory?

[image]

Comment: You can set path for android studio like this : flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"  and reopen terminal and check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **default** Android Studio directory should be `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`.

If you are searching for the Android SDK location, check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location).

The warning/error you are getting on `flutter doctor` is telling you that he cannot find Android Studio in the path `C:\Program`, this means you will need to set it manually. To do it, run the following command(s) with the correct path.

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir "[YOURPATH]"
flutter config --android-sdk "[YOURPATH]"
```

This should be the expected output of the `flutter doctor`

[image: Screenshot]

---

Remember to use those `" "` to indicate the path of Android Studio, otherwise you'll have this output, that is not what we want: `Setting "android-studio-dir" value to "C:\Program".`

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance. it works ! After I've been trying all day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
```

Which unfortunately does not work because of empty space which breaks the tree structure

To resolve this, type the command below which will reset the default.

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=""
```